# Entity Framework - Oracle DB: Intermittently throws “ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack”

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Sometimes, EF throw this error.

Exception stacktrace

```
   in OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   in OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   in OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
   in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Openb__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action3 executing, Action3 executed)
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Openb__2()
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

Inner exception stacktrace

```
   in OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   in OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   in OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
   in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action3 executing, Action3 executed)
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

Is a database problem or an entity framework problem? How can I resolve it?

Comment: It's a database issue. See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12516-tns_ould_not_find_available_handler.htm for possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

ORA-12516 is thrown when number of opened Oracle connections exceeds maximum allowed connections number.

If it happens for your application:

1. Make sure you close connections properly.
2. If you actually have high-loaded application where such big number of opened connections is required, increase this allowed maximum (`PROCESSES` setting in the Oracle configuration).

Check this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/362226) for the details.

Comment: how can i make sure I close connections properly? I am using EF, i thougth that it will manage automatically

Comment: Ah, that part isn't applied to EF, EF manages connections for you. Check how many opened connections you have when error happens and increase allowed maximum if it's reached.